# How do I derive the expression of boundary work in relation to a polytropic index?

Tags: thermodynamics, homework

I don't understand how to derive the formula,
[image]
How do I derive the expression of boundary work in relation to a polytropic index?
I used the Definition of boundary work for a polytropic index, the first and second laws to get the following:

[image]

How do I derive the expression of boundary work in relation to a polytropic index?
But I am unsure how to continue the derivation. How should I proceed?

The full question below: \n
[image]

Comment: Two questions.  Firstly, which do you want to derive: the expression for the boundary work, the expression for the (total) reversible work, or both?  Secondly, where do you want to start the derivation from, i.e. what do you already know?